# Xamarin Android: Sending data to an external activity and retrieving them from the result

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am trying to call the camera, with certain arguments, along with some extra data my activity needs to process the returned photo , 
I used this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(System.IO.Path.Combine(App.DatabaseFolder, ATTACHMENT_FILE));
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file));
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraScreenOrientation, (int)ScreenOrientation.Portrait);
intent.PutExtra("source_id", id); // here I put the extra data
StartActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST);
```

now I am trying to retrieve the id sent to the activity when the result comes back

is there a way to do that? I tried

```
if (requestCode = CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST && resultCode == Result.Ok) {
    data.GetIntExtra("source_id", -1);
}
```

but I can't seem to retrieve the result

as a workaround I managed to do the above by either saving the id in the result code or the file name, but I prefer to find another way, is there one?

In case you find the code weird, it is written in Xamarin Android, but it's still an android question

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Camera is an external application and don't collect your "extra info".

More info here : [AndroidDeveloer - Camera API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

So in your case you should store your id into a global variable or SharedPreferences